# What "as *const _" do? What does the "_" mean?

Tags: rust, syntax

Context: I needed to flatten a vector of arrays in Rust, and I found the following code from a Rust community member:

```rust
fn flatten<T: Clone, const N: usize>(data : Vec<[T; N]>) -> Vec<T> {
    unsafe {
        from_raw_parts(data.as_ptr() as *const _, data.len() * N).to_vec()
    }
}
```

`from_raw_parts` returns a slice from a raw pointer and a length. The raw pointer we're passing in has a type of `*const [T;N]`, and I figure we would need to convert that to `*const T`. However, this code converts it to `*const _` and produces the same result as using `*const T`.

So what is `_` doing here? And is it good practice to use `_` instead of an explicit type?

Comment: Note that this function is inefficient: it allocates a `Vec` while it could reuse the allocation (you can use [`bytemuck::cast_vec()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/allocation/fn.cast_vec.html)).

Comment: Also note that casting pointers using `as` is a bad practice: prefer [`cast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast) (because it is less dangerous).

Comment: I don't think I understand how `as` is bad practice when the source code for `cast()` is `self as _`

Comment: The entire idea is to implement it in library code so you don't have to do it yourself, you only get a more constrained, safer implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` just means "infer the type from the context". In this case, the compiler infers it to be `T` from the function's return type.

Regarding the second question, in general in Rust we tend to leave to the compiler what it can infer, but with unsafe code specifically because any mistake can be so dangerous I (and other people) prefer to specify each and every type explicitly.